# Как вставить приложение silverlight на сайт php

Tags: веб-программирование, silverlight, php

Здраствуйте, есть сайт на php. Как в него засунуть приложение сильверлайт? (т.к. хочу использовать возможности сильверлайта, но при этом сайт уже есть - на php, не на асп). Киньте пожалуйста ссылку, кто знает.

Comment: Да вряд ли кто-то знает:)

Comment: а сильверлайт через что общается с сервером? если с помощью XML, то наверно никакой разницы нету...

Answer (score 1):

Почти один-в-один так-же, как и flash: [How to: Add Silverlight to a Web Page by Using HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089(v=vs.95).aspx)